# Inferencing the typename of 'this' in a virtual method

Tags: c++11, templates

I am aware of the lack of reflection and basic template mechanics in C++ so the example below can't work. But maybe there's a hack to achieve the intended purpose in another way?

```
template <typename OwnerClass>
struct Template
{
    OwnerClass *owner;
};

struct Base
{
    virtual void funct ()
    {
        Template <decltype(*this)> temp;
        // ...
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    void whatever ()
    {
        // supposed to infer this class and use Template<Derived> 
        // any chance some macro or constexpr magic could help?
        funct(); 
    }
};
```

In the example, `Derived::whatever()` calls virtual method `Base::funct()` and wants it to pass its own class name (Derived) to a template. The compiler complains "`'owner' declared as a pointer to a reference of type 'Base &'`". Not only does `decltype(*this)` not provide a typename but a reference, the compiler also can't know in advance that funct is called from *Derived*, which would require `funct()` to be made a template.

If `funct()` was a template however, each derived class needs to pass its own name with every call, which is pretty verbose and redundant.

Is there any hack to get around this limitation and make calls to funct() infer the typename of the calling class? Maybe `constexpr` or `macros` to help the compiler infer the correct type and reduce verbosity in derived classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CRTP Pattern (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) for inheritance.

Define a base class:

```
struct CBase {
    virtual ~CBase() {}
    virtual void function() = 0;
};
```

Define a prepared to CRTP class:

```
template<typename T>
struct CBaseCrtp : public CBase {
    virtual ~CBaseCrtp() {}

    void function() override {
        using DerivedType = T;
        //do stuff
    }
};
```

Inherit from the CRTP one:

```
struct Derived : public CBaseCrtp<Derived> {

};
```

It should work. The only way to know the Derived type is to give it to the base!

Comment: It does work. Thanks @enoc-martinez Great solution actually, only that it gets complicated if there are more classes to derive from Derived. It seems to work only for a single level of inheritance. Maybe the desired behavior could be encapsulated in a small utility class and put aside with multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this can't be done. `Base` is a `Base` and nothing else at the time `Template <decltype(*this)>` is instantiated. You are trying to mix the static type system for an inheritance hierarchy inherently not resolved before runtime. This very same mechanism is the reason for not calling `virtual` member functions of an object during its construction.

At some point, this limitation might change in the future. One step towards this is demonstrated in the [Deducing this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0847r0.html).